# Firebase App Distribution Gradle/CLI not working in GitHub Actions

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, github-actions, firebase-cli

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-cli
Both of the options, Gradle or CLI are not working for the firebase app distribution in GitHub Actions, For Gradle, it is giving error "Failed to detect whether we are running on google compute engine" for cli, error is provided in screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am also facing similar problem, did you find resolution ? I am getting 400 error.

Comment: @Tas you might want to set the FIREBASE_TOKEN as environment variable as in my post below. you can also send the token as parameters in triggered action.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me, it was an issue in setting the FIREBASE_TOKEN as environment variable.

```
name: FIREBASE APP DISTRIBUTION

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: UPLOAD APP TO FIREBASE

jobs:
  build:
    env:
      FIREBASE_TOKEN: *****************************************

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Branch ${{ github.event.client_payload.branch }}
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.client_payload.branch }}
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Preparing Gradle Executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Building apk for ${{ github.event.client_payload.build_variant }}
        run: ./gradlew assemble${{ github.event.client_payload.build_variant }} appDistributionUpload${{ github.event.client_payload.build_variant }} -PvName="${{ github.event.client_payload.version_name }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of Rishi's [owner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734069/791609), it might worth moving the environment variable setup to the workflow level, so that the environment configurations can be shared across different jobs:

```
name: FIREBASE APP DISTRIBUTION

on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: UPLOAD APP TO FIREBASE

env:
  FIREBASE_TOKEN: *****************************************

jobs:
  build:
```